# Heroku error on deployment - ( Request Timeout )

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a reactjs / nodejs app being run, and I am trying to host with Heroku... The app is deployed live, but I cant actually load anything. In my logs I see this:

```
     2021-04-18T23:41:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-18T23:42:14.395000+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN shared@1.0.0 No description
2021-04-18T23:42:14.422024+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN shared@1.0.0 No repository field.
2021-04-18T23:42:14.422890+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-18T23:42:14.682226+00:00 app[web.1]: added 1 package from 6 contributors and audited 486 packages in 17.344s
2021-04-18T23:42:15.300879+00:00 app[web.1]: found 56017 vulnerabilities (40514 low, 15 moderate, 15488 high)
2021-04-18T23:42:15.300903+00:00 app[web.1]: run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2021-04-18T23:42:15.361457+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/shared -> /app/shared
2021-04-18T23:42:15.391152+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/react-web/node_modules/shared -> /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/shared -> /app/shared
2021-04-18T23:42:16.015673+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-18T23:42:16.015683+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-web@0.1.0 start /app/react-web
2021-04-18T23:42:16.015687+00:00 app[web.1]: > node --max_old_space_size=2560 checkEnvironmentForBuild && react-app-rewired start
2021-04-18T23:42:16.015687+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-18T23:42:20.857742+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.225.30/
2021-04-18T23:42:20.858248+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2021-04-18T23:42:20.858378+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/react-web/public
2021-04-18T23:42:20.858506+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2021-04-18T23:42:20.858836+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2021-04-18T23:42:20.858837+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-18T23:42:21.460296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-18T23:42:52.656047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=cleaningassistant.herokuapp.com request_id=3b1180dc-c080-4624-8a97-d9247577dc3f fwd="99.249.30.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

it is basically saying `Request Timeout`, when all my start scripts are correct. The only thing it could be looking for is for me to define a port. The problem is, this isn't a nodejs app, its reactjs, so not sure what to do there.

app set up:
[image]

please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Can you share the output of `heroku logs`?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I've edited to show my logs... I now have the error -- request timeout!

Comment: I have noticed that your files seem to be placed on the `/app/shared` folder on Heroku, while your files are being served from `/app/react-web/public`. Is that correct?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesAragon I've just edited my question to show the directory config. If the main directory is considered to be `app`, then yes, technically it would be doing that

Comment: My point is precisely that I believe your files are being placed on `/app/shared`, but your application is remotely being served from `/app/public`. You should place the contents of the deploy inside the `/app/public` for them to be served. This might cause you some confusion, because the `public` folder you have locally will not correspond to the one you have remotely. One alternative is to build your application , either locally or remotely, and place it inside the `/app/public` folder.